# WPF: how to bind my collection from different Page

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, propertychanged

So i have this `Collection` inside my `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ObservableCollection<NetworkInterface> _interfaces;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Interfaces = NetworkInterface.ReadAll();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<NetworkInterface> Interfaces
        {
            get { return _interfaces; }
            set
            {
                _interfaces = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This `NetworkInterface` is implement `PropertyChanged` and when the application start its full with items.

Initialize my `ViewMode`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     viewModel = new ViewModel();
 }
```

I have another `Page` in my application that load inside `Frame` after button `Click`:

```
<Grid Name="GridMain" Grid.Row="1">
          <Frame Name="MyFrame"
                 NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
                 Source="Pages/home.xaml"/>
</Grid>
```

Load the `Page`:

```
Home home = new Home();
MyFrame.Content = home;
```

And inside my `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Interfaces}" Height="30" Width="300"/>
```

I also try:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Interfaces}" Height="30" Width="300"/>
```

But still my `ComboBox` is empty

**EDIT**

If this `ComboBox` is inside the main application and not inside `Page` this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` is not the `DataContext` of the `Page` in the `Frame`. You may set the DataContext of the Frame programmatically though:

The `Page` in the `Frame` doesn't automatically inherit the `DataContext` from the `MainWindow`, but you can set its `DataContext` property when you load the `Page`:

```
Home home = new Home();
home.DataContext = viewModel;
MyFrame.Content = home;
```